# Installing Gurobi in Virtualenv without Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, anaconda, gurobi

I would like to use [Gurobi Optimization library](http://www.gurobi.com/) with Python3.5 inside a `virtualenv` environment, without having to install the whole Anaconda Framework. This implies to be able to install Gurobi library (`gurobipy`) via Pipy.

On Gurobi website is only explained [how to install it with Anaconda](http://www.gurobi.com/downloads/get-anaconda) and conda package manager, using the commands:

```
conda config --add channels http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi
conda install gurobi
```

I do **not** understand how (and why!) a Python library would require Python to be installed as a Framework to work well (`matplotlib` often bothers, but does not **requires** it). 
Isn't there any way to convert this command `conda config --add channels ***` into a similar command for `Pypi`, so I could eventually `rm -rf` my 98%-useless 2Gb Anaconda stack?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are [instructions to install gurobipy](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/quickstart_linux/the_gurobi_python_interfac.html) in your own Python distribution by running `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could do that directly. Is there a way to obtain the setup.py without having to install Gurobi first?

Comment: No. Gurobi contains native code that needs to be installed correctly for your system.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a while, and the instructions did not quite work for me. In my case, what worked was to copy the 'python.exe' file from the python native folder into the gurobi folder, where the 'setup.py' is located. Then, I have first to execute `python setup.py build` and then execute 'python setup.py install'. Also, be sure to check that both your python and gurobi are 64 or 32 bits.